# Getting error after upgrading Xcode and react native version

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am getting the error `library not found for -lboost_context` while building and archiving the project from Xcode 12.4. React native version 0.64.0

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX64v.jpg)

Comment: What version of MacOS are you on? I have seen this often that as soon as XCode releases a new update, something in React Native breaks. Same is the issue with MacOS 11.3.1 and XCode 12.5

Comment: using 11.2.3 MacOS version

Comment: As I mentioned, I had a similar problem and the only option was to downgrade XCode to the previously working version. Followed this guide: https://www.wootechy.com/iphone-issue/downgrade-xcode/

Comment: @Ajay Dont you need to have xcode updated to the latest version to public an app to the store?

Comment: @Auticcat not sure but I have been in situations where a release was pending and the latest version of Xcode had issues with React Native. But we were able to release the app anyways. Again, not sure.